# 'Cache folder contains root-owned files' when deploying react app on openshift using Tekton

Tags: reactjs, openshift, tekton

I am deploying the frontend of my react application on openshift 4.13 using tekton CI and this is my dockerfile

```
# Use an official Node.js image as the base
FROM node:alpine

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm cache clean --force

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files
COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

# Install the dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the entire project directory into the container
COPY --chown=node:node . .

# Build the React app
RUN npm run build


RUN npm cache clean --force
# Set ownership and permissions for the additional directory
RUN chgrp -R 0 /app && chmod -R g=u /app



# Set the command to run the application
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

When the pod is running i get crash loop back-off and gives this logs:

```
Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
 previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
 To permanently fix this problem, please run:
 sudo chown -R 1000710000:0 "/.npm"
 Log files were not written due to an error writing to the directory: /.npm/_logs
 You can rerun the command with `--loglevel=verbose` to see the logs in your terminal
```

Any help would be appreciated ..

I tried to change to the latest version of npm node , and i added this line to the dockerfile `RUN chgrp -R 0 /app && chmod -R g=u /app`

Answer (score 0):

That one really sounds like an issue with your environment, unrelated to Tekton:

```
Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
 previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
 To permanently fix this problem, please run:
 sudo chown -R 1000710000:0 "/.npm"
```

To fix, I would:

- set some HOME environment variable. Eg: HOME=/app
- make sure there's a .npm folder under that home directory, which can be written to. In your case: adding some emptyDir volume, and attach it as /app/.npm

While ... going further ... building your image, your chowning/chmoding files .... 1/ are you sure your runtime user, in openshift, actually benefits from this? 2/ I would argue your container image should be immutable: application code being able to re-write itself sounds like a design flaw.

Comment: Regarding your point 2, first off it's a cache not being writable, not code trying to (or even being able to!) rewrite itself. Secondly, if docker containers should be truly immutable then any container using any kind of cache wouldn't be useful. Cache is a completely valid requirement imo, and if so then docker containers shouldn't be immutable (and they usually aren't, most can use folders like `/tmp`)